# Improperly stored hours, easy way to parse "minutes" out of a decimal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that stores hours and minutes like so:

hh:mm

so for example, one and a half hours = 1.35 (where the "35"= 35 minutes). I need to figure out a good way to parse this, so that I can sum it. So I'd like =>

```
TimeID        UniqueID
1.30          A
2.30          A
1.15          B
1.15          B
....
```

To result as

```
A=3
B=.5 (Because it's half of an hour)
```

I know I can divide the decimal part by 60, but I'm not certain how to put it all together.

Something along the lines of the bellow to parse out the `timeID`?

```
Select sum(cast(timeID as varchar(4)),uniqueID
From exampleTable
groupby uniqueID
```

My concern with this is mainly that I'd have to cast it to varchar, parse the decimal, and then reparse to a float

Comment: How does A = 3 and B = .5? Wouldn't A = 4 and B = 2.5? or if you are only summing minutes, A = 1 and B = .5?

Comment: `hh:mm` is not `1.35`, so that is a little confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `% 1` to get the fractional part of a number.  The rest is arithmetic:

```
select uniqueid,
       sum(floor(timeid) + 100 * (timeid % 1) / 60.0)
from t
group by uniqueid;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ace02cfba49b3838479a5b0aeb814f7c) is a db<>fiddle.